# Is Collier's line about the bible correct?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, fury

In Fury, Brad Pitt said: "You see, we can kill them (women), but we can't fuck them, 'cause it said so in the Bible." Did the Bible really said that?

Comment: No. The bible has a lot of weird stuff in it, but I don't think the f-word is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the exact phrasing is obviously *not* in the bible that way. Rather than that this was just a quite cynical comment from *"Wardaddy"* regarding the difficult moral situation they're in. While *Collier* hasn't lost any sense or morality yet, he is on his best way to that and the war has turned him into a hardened, brutal and cynical person.

So what he wanted to say with this is, that on the one hand they are on a supposedly righteous cause backed by god and all that. And it would surely not be regarded of good Christian morale to run around and *"fuck"* all those women. But on the other hand, while their cause ultimately seems a good one, they are practically devastating the lands they cross as well and *Collier* is realistic or cynical enough to know that there have been killed enough innocents by his side, too, all with the moral backing of being on the "good" side, though. He's alluding to the double morale of the bible (supposedly) encouraging war with all it's gruesomeness while still posing other totally unrelated moral limitations.

So I wouldn't take that comment too literal, it is a very cynical comment on the rather muddled moral ground they're moving in the whole time. In addition to that, if I remember correctly, he said that when they were riding the tank and he stood next to *Boyd* (who didn't have the nickname *"Bible"* without reason), so I'd guess he also wanted to provoke him a bit with such a rather inaccurate or cynical comment about the bible (which, if I remember correctly, worked, since *Boyd* was quite pissed at that comment).

Comment: To get theologically technical, you'd have to lay the Christian justification of warfare at the feet of St. Augustine, not the Bible. The Bible says "Don't Murder"...St. Augustine's doctrine was that warfare (within certain bounds) is not murder.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens I'd surmise that *Collier* didn't make that distinction at that moment either, though. But yeah, I also guessed the bible doesn't really encourage to war directly.